# google nearby places search not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

Sorry for asking help for such a newbie question. But it is very confusing to use maps api. It is not showing anything for type country or sometimes its just showing same results as of type:store for type:establishment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 500px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>

var nlat, nlong;

nlat= 19.0759837;  //default
nlong = 72.87765590000004;  // default

getLocation();
      function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    nlat = position.coords.latitude;
    nlong = position.coords.longitude;
}

      var map;
      var infowindow;
      var plcsearch = "";

      function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: nlat, lng: nlong},
          zoom: 10
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: {lat: nlat, lng: nlong},
          radius: 5000000,
          type: ['country']
        }, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
            plcsearch = plcsearch + "<br>" + results[i].name;
          }
        }
        var x = document.getElementById("plcrad");
  x.innerHTML = plcsearch;
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="plcrad">List of Countries</div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCEBvD7N9NkG4_1xAFPpPH6FTJLIk-_2TY
&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Also you can just see same problem here also : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search
Please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `country` is no valid type for requests, see https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1

Answer (score 0):

In support of Dr.Molle's comment, country is not a valid type for search request.

*Place Types*

Here is some list of supported type that can be used to filter for place searches and when adding a place.

- accounting
- airport
- amusement_park
- aquarium
- art_gallery
- atm
- bakery
- bank
- bar
- beauty_salon

For your other concern regarding the same result for establishment or store, here is a sample response for search:

```
"place_id" : "ChIJ5xQ7szeuEmsRs6Kj7YFZE9k",
"scope" : "GOOGLE",
"reference" : "CnRvAAAA22k1PAGyDxAgHZk6ErHh_h_mLUK_8XNFLvixPJHXRbCzg-gw1ZxdqUwA_8EseDuEZKolBs82orIQH4m6-afDZV9VcpggokHD9x7HdMi9TnJDmGb9Bdh8f-Od4DK0fASNBL7Me3CsAWkUMWhlNQNYExIQ05W7VbxDTQe2Kh9TiL840hoUZfiO0q2HgDHSUyRdvTQx5Rs2SBU",
"types" : [ "food", "establishment" ],
"vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
```

As the response indicate, a place can have more than one type depending on how they have been added. For better understanding on how or why some search request returns same result we can double check on the response and see the types tags for each places.

For reference, you can further view [types supported in place search and addition](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1), [types not supported in the type filter of a place search](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table2), and [search Responses](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses).